# Kendo UI Image Upload Restriction for file type isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I want to restrict image upload to only jpg images using the kendo UI for ASP .NET MVC3. However, when I followed the [example here](http://jsbin.com/upekan/1/edit),even with my manipulation below, it keeps alerting "please upload jpg image files" even when I uploaded a jpg file! In fact, it makes me select all kinds of images. How can I change it so that I can only upload jpg images and if I upload png or other type of image files, it should alert, to only upload jpg images.

I put this into one of my views:

```
<script>
var onSelect = function (e) {
    $.each(e.files, function (index, value) {
        var ok = value.extension == ".JPG"
                 || value.extension == ".JPEG"
                 || value.extension == ".jpg"
                 || value.extension == ".jpeg";

        if (value.extension != ok) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Please upload jpg image files");
        }
    });
};

// initialize and configure an Upload widget with a select event handler
$("#photos").kendoUpload({
    select: onSelect
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a type-o:

```
value.expresion == ".jpg"
```

Should be:

```
value.expression == ".jpg"
```

Notice you are missing an 's'

**EDIT**

`value.extension` is a string which contains the extension. And `ok` is a boolean which determines if the correct extension was provided, so what you want to use to determine if to display the alert should be displayed needs to be udpated:

```
if (!ok) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("Please upload jpg image files");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I meant to put extension actually. I fixed the mistake but I'm still getting the same error. The alert message appears regardless of jpg or png. This in Google Chrome browser.

Comment: Now I'm wondering how to connect my uploaded images to a db. Hmmm